# Как в Python & PyQt5 в панель с вкладками подгружать содержимое вкладки из другого класса?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть класс MainWindow, в котором есть панель с вкладками. Одну из вкладок формирует класс FactorsTab, находящийся в файле FactorsTabWidget.py.

при запуске вылетает с ошибкой:

> line 13, in **init** self.table =
>   QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors) AttributeError:
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'QStandardItemModel'

*line 13 у меня: self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors)*

```
file main.py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        factors_tab = FactorsTabWidget.FactorsTab()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(factors_tab, "Factors")        

file FactorsTabWidget.py
class FactorsTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.frame_factors = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors)
        self.lst1 = ['Дискета', 'Бумага для принтера', 'Барабан для принтера']
        self.lst2 = ["10", "3", "10452048"]
        for row in range(0, 3):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst1[row])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst2[row])
            self.table.appendRow([item1, item2])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Factor Name', 'Кол-во'])
        self.frame_factors.setModel(self.table)
```

как правильно сформировать содержимое вкладки из другого класса?

Answer (score 1):

путем тыка нашел такое решение:

**main.py:**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.factors_tab = FactorsTab()
        self.table_tab = TableTab()        
        self.box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.factors_tab, "Factors")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.table_tab, "Table of coding factors")        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabs.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabs.setLayout(self.box)
        self.add_menu()
```

**FactorsTabWidget.py**

```
class FactorsTab(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Select folder, project file name")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.frame_factors = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
        self.lst1 = ['Дискета', 'Бумага для принтера', 'Барабан для принтера']
        self.lst2 = ["10", "3", "10452048"]
        for row in range(0, 3):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst1[row])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst2[row])
            self.table.appendRow([item1, item2])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Factor Name', 'Кол-во'])
        self.frame_factors.setModel(self.table)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.frame_factors)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```